# Show User's Current Time

Tags: plugin-development

I am developing a Plugin. I would like to display User's Time.

I am using this code.

```
date('g:i A');
```

But I am not getting exact time.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705067/how-can-i-get-the-users-local-time-instead-of-the-servers-time) post. But I didn't get any solution.

How can I Show User's current time ?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not in the browser.  PHP does not know what timezone the user is in.  The SO post you have linked makes this clear.  Pass the time from JS back to PHP with ajax.

Comment: Thanks @jdm2112. How this Plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/location-weather) showing Time ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a problem using a api you can do the following.

```php
// check if user IP exists
if (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    // get user data based on IP (not always correct)
    $user_ip_data = file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '/json');

    // check if is json object
    if (!empty($user_ip_data) && $user_ip_data[0] === '{' && substr($user_ip_data, -1) === '}') {
        // create php object from json
        $user_ip_data = json_decode($user_ip_data);

        // check if timezone exists
        if (!empty($user_ip_data->timezone)) {
            // create new date time object based on the user timezone
            $date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($user_ip_data->timezone));

            // output the time
            echo $date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
        }
    }
}
```

I provided comments for each line of code so you could better understand what each of them does.

Tested it using a vpn to check if timezone changes, and it does.